# Missing component in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

[image]

I experienced a missing component in ADO.NET, namely in model.tt which should contain table data as shown below

[image]

at that time when I wanted to re-add the database but when it was re-added the components in the second picture disappeared

error is
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating548217BD8377E326AEE514EAE722C9BA6586C4151F980CA7BACC70A5732FC55F588FBC8794326CD64388F9B4C50AD7729497DE610EBC8D6F64F48BB130F68063.GeneratedTextTransformation.DynamicTextTransformation.get_GenerationEnvironment()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating548217BD8377E326AEE514EAE722C9BA6586C4151F980CA7BACC70A5732FC55F588FBC8794326CD64388F9B4C50AD7729497DE610EBC8D6F64F48BB130F68063.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTransformation)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating548217BD8377E326AEE514EAE722C9BA6586C4151F980CA7BACC70A5732FC55F588FBC8794326CD64388F9B4C50AD7729497DE610EBC8D6F64F48BB130F68063.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTemplating)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating548217BD8377E326AEE514EAE722C9BA6586C4151F980CA7BACC70A5732FC55F588FBC8794326CD64388F9B4C50AD7729497DE610EBC8D6F64F48BB130F68063.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(Object textTransformation)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating548217BD8377E326AEE514EAE722C9BA6586C4151F980CA7BACC70A5732FC55F588FBC8794326CD64388F9B4C50AD7729497DE610EBC8D6F64F48BB130F68063.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() Latihan E:\Software project\HovLibrary\Latihan\Model1.tt    1

Comment: open the edmx file, right click on an empty space and hit "rebuild models" (or something  implying this function, no idea what it is actually called)

Comment: i will try it tomorrow

Comment: Has your issue progressed? A fix in EFTools.msi may also help

Comment: where is  EFTools.msi ??

Comment: @DAFDZIKHO There is a hidden folder called ProgramData in the C drive, find the Package Cache folder. Search for EFTools inside.